# How to Run the simulation from an external user interface which identical to Anylogic simulation window?

Tags: anylogic

In my project, I need to discard the inbuilt Anylogic database and use an external Db, where the table include the parameters in the simulation which are inserted from a UI and the database is acting as the data stream channel. The main reason to do this to imitate a physical system into Anylogic.
1. Simulation - Anylogic.
2. Database server - MySQL.
3. UI - Windows form.
I want to know if I can run the simulation based on the changes done in the database from UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be a problem.  We have had AnyLogic models pull in data from AWS databases.  Remember, under the hood AnyLogic is Java, so if you can write a Java program to connect to a database, you can have your AnyLogic model talk to a database, other than the internal database.  You may want to rethink some of your data structures.  Maybe things that automatically instantiated from an AL database will need to have a little bit of code to query an external database and then instantiate the agents/objects.  You can import an external database to the AL database, so it may be that you continue to use it, just importing from another source.  The exact implementation could vary wildly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I defined a java class inside AL as a query and also extended it to Main to reference them into individual logic blocks. But, I want to know the possibility of Running the experiment window with run() command queried from external DB during runtime?

Comment: Are you saying you have an external database application that you want to 1) launch the model and then 2) have the model talk to that database while running?  Sounds like you have #2 figured out.  If you are asking about #1, the answer is yes.  In the help menu is the code required to launch a simulation model from an external application.  Of course, all files would have to be present in the correct location for this code to work.  You can also export your model to an application & by examining the .bat file get some clues on how to set up these external commands.

Comment: #2 is my use case and #1 is the method of implementation. Thank you very much for your validation